# Как создать Модель ADO.NET EDM на платформе .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Пишу свой проект и я не могу создать модель, так как она работает только с .NET Framework. Можно ли как-то создать модель, не создавая для этого отдельный проект? Или придётся пересоздавать проект на платформе .NET Framework?

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать нормальные инструменты для работы с базой, EF например. Какой смысл использовать что-то низкоуровневое?

Comment: Используйте Entity Framework Core.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , я просто начинающий. Спасибо что подсказали! Нашёл актуальную документацию.